# Consuming spark RDD using Kafka

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka

Are there any samples in JAVA to consume spark RDD in JAVA using Kafka, If there is one please let me know

I am trying out a few things but i am unsure as to how to send an RDD in a producer and consume it in Kafka consumer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For writing your RDD to kafka you can use cloudera's API. Here is the [link](https://github.com/cloudera/spark-kafka-writer).

Answer (score 0):

Code will be like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.*;

 JavaPairReceiverInputDStream<String, String> directKafkaStream = 
     KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(streamingContext,
         [key class], [value class], [key decoder class], [value decoder class],
         [map of Kafka parameters], [set of topics to consume]);
```

Have a look at [kafka-integration](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-integration.html) and [code example](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/JavaKafkaWordCount.java)